# How do I drag an image smoothly around the screen using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use JavaScript drag an image around the screen. I've already written a script that works fine on divs with text, but when I use it on a image it works very intermittently.

I have put my code on jsfiddle so others can see what I mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/laurence/YNMEX/

If you run it you will find that the text block can be dragged and dropped, but when you try the same thing with the image, it leaves the image behind. It's like the image can't keep up with the movement of the mouse.

I have repeated the code on jsfiddle below:

```js
function startDrag(e) {
  // determine event object
  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event;
  }

  // IE uses srcElement, others use target
  var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

  if (targ.className != 'dragme') {
    return
  };
  // calculate event X, Y coordinates
  offsetX = e.clientX;
  offsetY = e.clientY;

  // assign default values for top and left properties
  if (!targ.style.left) {
    targ.style.left = '0px'
  };
  if (!targ.style.top) {
    targ.style.top = '0px'
  };

  // calculate integer values for top and left 
  // properties
  coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
  coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
  drag = true;

  // move div element
  document.onmousemove = dragDiv;
}

function dragDiv(e) {
  if (!drag) {
    return
  };
  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event
  };
  var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
  // move div element
  targ.style.left = coordX + e.clientX - offsetX + 'px';
  targ.style.top = coordY + e.clientY - offsetY + 'px';
  return false;
}

function stopDrag() {
  drag = false;
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.onmousedown = startDrag;
  document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
}
```

```css
.dragme {
  position: relative;
  width: 270px;
  height: 203px;
  cursor: move;
}

#draggable {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable" class="dragme">"Hello World!"</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/270/203" alt="drag-and-drop image script" title="drag-and-drop image script" class="dragme">
```

Comment: +1 for trying a pure javascript solution. Now we only need to wait for the "use jquery" herd to come stomping in :).

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply add `return false` at the end of your `startDrag` function to keep the browser from handling the click event.

Comment: Nice! Just tried it in the Fiddle and it works flawlessly. I'm thinking of turning this into a simple browser based Javascript Chess game :)

Comment: @Parrotmaster http://jsfiddle.net/YNMEX/1/ (in addition to `return false` also notice the `preventDefault`.

Comment: Thank you Darmesh Patel and n3rd for your help and for being so prompt in answering my question. Thank you Parrotmaster for put the correct verion of my script on JSFiddle

Answer (score 12):

Also `targ` should be assigned only on `startDrag` and `global` (without var):

http://jsfiddle.net/gigyme/YNMEX/132/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startDrag(e) {
            // determine event object
            if (!e) {
                var e = window.event;
            }
            if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

            // IE uses srcElement, others use target
            targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

            if (targ.className != 'dragme') {return};
            // calculate event X, Y coordinates
                offsetX = e.clientX;
                offsetY = e.clientY;

            // assign default values for top and left properties
            if(!targ.style.left) { targ.style.left='0px'};
            if (!targ.style.top) { targ.style.top='0px'};

            // calculate integer values for top and left 
            // properties
            coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
            coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
            drag = true;

            // move div element
                document.onmousemove=dragDiv;
            return false;

        }
        function dragDiv(e) {
            if (!drag) {return};
            if (!e) { var e= window.event};
            // var targ=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;
            // move div element
            targ.style.left=coordX+e.clientX-offsetX+'px';
            targ.style.top=coordY+e.clientY-offsetY+'px';
            return false;
        }
        function stopDrag() {
            drag=false;
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            document.onmousedown = startDrag;
            document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It works like charm. How to enable touch event for touch screen devices (tablets and smartphones) to this script?

Comment: I wanted to drag images as well, so I copied Gigy's script with no changes from the jsfiddle.  When I try to drag the flower the cursor changes to a 'no entry' symbol.  What is causing that to happen?

Answer (score 10):

You may add `e.preventDefault();` at the end of your `startDrag` function

Answer (score 0):

Bind a **specific element** of the drag event.

```
function log() {
    var debug = true;
    if (!debug)
        return;
    if (arguments) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            console.log(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
}    

function Drag(element) {
    this.dragging = false;
    this.mouseDownPositionX = 0;
    this.mouseDownPositionY = 0;
    this.elementOriginalLeft = 0;
    this.elementOriginalTop = 0;
    var ref = this;
    this.startDrag = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ref.dragging = true;
        ref.mouseDownPositionX = e.clientX;
        ref.mouseDownPositionY = e.clientY;
        ref.elementOriginalLeft = parseInt(element.style.left);
        ref.elementOriginalTop = parseInt(element.style.top);
        // set mousemove event
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', ref.dragElement);
        log('startDrag');
    };
    this.unsetMouseMove = function () {
        // unset mousemove event
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', ref.dragElement);
    };
    this.stopDrag = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ref.dragging = false;
        ref.unsetMouseMove();
        log('stopDrag');
    };
    this.dragElement = function (e) {
        log('dragging');
        if (!ref.dragging)
            return;
        e.preventDefault();
        // move element
        element.style.left = ref.elementOriginalLeft + (e.clientX - ref.mouseDownPositionX) + 'px';
        element.style.top = ref.elementOriginalTop + (e.clientY - ref.mouseDownPositionY) + 'px';
        log('dragElement');
    };
    element.onmousedown = this.startDrag;
    element.onmouseup = this.stopDrag;
}

var myDrag = new Drag(yourElement);// bind event
console.log(myDrag.dragging);
```