# Image drag not working

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I know i can make it with jQuery, but i want to do it with JavaScript only so i can improve my skills, but i can't make it work... I want to make my image draggable... I know i can make it with $('img').draggable(); with jQuery, all i want to do is improve my JS skills, i tried to look at the source of jquery ui but i couldn't understand it properly. Could someone help me ? I got this logic:

```
* I know i need to start the drag function when i click the img
 * I know i need to move the img in the x-y positions of the body
 * I know how to get the position while passing the mouse over the body
```

But i can't make the image do be draggable. Here's an example of what i have:

```
var img = document.querySelector("#img-teste");

img.onmousedown = function(){
    img.onmousemove = function(e){
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;

        img.style.left = x+'px';
        img.style.top = y +'px';
    }
}
img.onmouseup = function(){
    img.onmousemove = null;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4sj5218/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and drop without JQuery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435051/drag-and-drop-without-jquery-ui)

Comment: @dsg, Hi, thanks for looking at my question but that's not duplicate at all. I want to know how to code this, i have all the logic in my head but the doesn't work. Got it ?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't make the image be draggable

You are close. You have

```
img.style.left = x+'px';
img.style.top = y+'px';
```

To use a `left` or `top` style, the element must be `position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`.

**Example:**

```
#img-teste{
    position:absolute;
    width:15%;
    height:15%;
}
```

---

For another implementation of smoothly dragging an image around with pure JS, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992543/how-do-i-drag-an-image-smoothly-around-the-screen-using-pure-javascript).