# How to drag images in JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, events

I have a large background image and some much smaller images for the user to drag around on the background. I need this to be efficient in terms of performance, so i'm trying to avoid libraries. I'm fine with drag 'n' drop if it work's well, but im trying to get drag.

Im pretty much trying to do [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992543/how-do-i-drag-an-image-smoothly-around-the-screen-using-pure-javascript/17992765) But after 8 years there must be a cleaner way to do this right?

I currently have a drag 'n' drop system that almost works, but when i drop the smaller images, they are just a little off and it's very annoying. Is there a way to fix my code, or do i need to take a whole different approach?

This is my code so far:

```js
var draggedPoint;

function dragStart(event) {
  draggedPoint = event.target; // my global var
}


function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let xDiff = draggedPoint.x - event.pageX;
  let yDiff = draggedPoint.y - event.pageY;

  let left = draggedPoint.style.marginLeft; // get margins
  let top = draggedPoint.style.marginTop;

  let leftNum = Number(left.substring(0, left.length - 2)); // cut off px from the end
  let topNum = Number(top.substring(0, top.length - 2));

  let newLeft = leftNum - xDiff + "px" // count new margins and put px back to the end
  let newTop = topNum - yDiff + "px"

  draggedPoint.style.marginLeft = newLeft;
  draggedPoint.style.marginTop = newTop;
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}


let imgs = [
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Orange_juice_1_edit1.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Litoria_infrafrenata_-_Julatten.jpg"
]

/* my smaller images: */
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let sensor = document.createElement("img");
    sensor.src = imgs[i % imgs.length];
    sensor.alt = i;
    sensor.draggable = true;
    sensor.classList.add("sensor");

    sensor.style.marginLeft = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 900)}px`
    sensor.style.marginTop = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)}px`

    sensor.onclick = function() {
       sensorClick(logs[i].id)
    };
    sensor.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart, null);

    let parent = document.getElementsByClassName("map")[0];
    parent.appendChild(sensor);
}
```

```html
<!-- my html: -->
<style>
     .map {
         width: 900px;
         height: 500px;
         align-content: center;
         margin: 150px auto 150px auto;
    }

     .map .base {
          position: absolute;
          width: inherit;
          height: inherit;
      }

    .map .sensor {
         position: absolute;
         width: 50px;
         height: 50px;
    }
</style>

<div class="map" onDrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Plan-Oum-el-Awamid.jpg' alt="pohja" class="base" draggable="false">
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992543/how-do-i-drag-an-image-smoothly-around-the-screen-using-pure-javascript/17992765) and some time i was able to get a smooth drag and click with pure js.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/djq2ec7r/19/) to see it in action.

```js
let maxLeft;
let maxTop;
const minLeft = 0;
const minTop = 0;
let timeDelta;
let imgs = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Orange_juice_1_edit1.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Solid_blue.svg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Litoria_infrafrenata_-_Julatten.jpg"
]
var originalX;
var originalY;

window.onload = function() {
    document.onmousedown = startDrag;
    document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
}
    
function sensorClick () {
    if (Date.now() - timeDelta < 150) { // check that we didn't drag
        createPopup(this);
    }
}

// create a popup when we click
function createPopup(parent) {
    let p = document.getElementById("popup");
    if (p) {
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }

    let popup = document.createElement("div");
    popup.id = "popup";
    popup.className = "popup";
    popup.style.top = parent.y - 110 + "px";
    popup.style.left = parent.x - 75 + "px";

    let text = document.createElement("span");
    text.textContent = parent.id;
    popup.appendChild(text);
    
    var map = document.getElementsByClassName("map")[0];
    map.appendChild(popup);
}

// when our base is loaded
function baseOnLoad() {
    var map = document.getElementsByClassName("map")[0];
    let base = document.getElementsByClassName("base")[0];
    maxLeft = base.width - 50;
    maxTop = base.height - 50;

    /* my smaller images: */
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        let sensor = document.createElement("img");
        sensor.src = imgs[i % imgs.length];
        sensor.alt = i;
        sensor.id = i;
        sensor.draggable = true;
        sensor.classList.add("sensor");
        sensor.classList.add("dragme");
        sensor.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 900)}px`
        sensor.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)}px`
        sensor.onclick = sensorClick;

        let parent = document.getElementsByClassName("map")[0];
        parent.appendChild(sensor);
    }
}

function startDrag(e) { 
    timeDelta = Date.now(); // get current millis

    // determine event object
    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    // prevent default event
    if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    // IE uses srcElement, others use target
    targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    originalX = targ.style.left;
    originalY = targ.style.top;

    // check that this is a draggable element
    if (!targ.classList.contains('dragme')) return;
    
    // calculate event X, Y coordinates
    offsetX = e.clientX;
    offsetY = e.clientY;

    // calculate integer values for top and left properties
    coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
    coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
    drag = true;

    document.onmousemove = dragDiv; // move div element
    return false; // prevent default event
}

function dragDiv(e) {
    if (!drag) return;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    // move div element and check for borders
    let newLeft = coordX + e.clientX - offsetX;
    if (newLeft < maxLeft && newLeft > minLeft) targ.style.left = newLeft + 'px'
    
    let newTop = coordY + e.clientY - offsetY;
    if (newTop < maxTop && newTop > minTop) targ.style.top = newTop + 'px'

    return false; // prevent default event
}

function stopDrag() {
    if (typeof drag == "undefined") return;

    if (drag) {
        if (Date.now() - timeDelta > 150) { // we dragged
            let p = document.getElementById("popup");
            if (p) {
                p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
            }
        } else {
            targ.style.left = originalX;
            targ.style.top = originalY;
        }
    }

    drag = false;
}
```

```css
.map {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 50px
    position: relative;
}

.map .base {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}

.map .sensor {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.dragme {
    cursor: move;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.popup {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #9FC990;
    border-radius: 10%;
}


.popup::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #9FC990 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.popup span {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="map" width="950px" height="500px">
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Plan-Oum-el-Awamid.jpg' alt="pohja" class="base" draggable="false" onload="baseOnLoad()">
<div>
```